# Can I call a function of base type class when calling store() of atomic? C++

Tags: c++, atomic

In my code, I have an atomic array of objects I have created from a self defined class. In short, the class looks like this:

```
class myObj{
public:
    //some members here...

    //constructor
    myObj()noexcept{
        //some code here
    }

    //function I want to call
    void myFunc(){//some code here}
};
```

Now let's say I have a single atomic object, instead of an array. I would declare it in main.cpp like below:

```
std::atomic<myObj> atomic_var;
```

I of course want to (atomically) store something in the variable above. Thus, I first create a temporary `myObj`, then I call `.store()` on my atomic variable.

```
myObj temp;
atomic_var.store(temp, std::memory_order_...);
```

where memory order does not matter right now.

Is it possible to call `myObj::myFunc()` when `.store()` is called as above?

Thank you.

Comment: One way is to write a wrapper over std::atomic

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to call `myObj::myFunc()` when .store() is called as above?

`std::atomic<myObj>::is_lock_free` is `false` because `myObj` is a user-defined type. That means that `std::atomic<myObj>` is implemented using a mutex, but that mutex isn't exposed.

What you can do is make that mutex a data member of `myObj` and implement `myObj& operator=(myObj const&)` to lock that mutex, do its job (e.g. also call `myObj::myFunc()`) and then unlock the mutex. And use `myObj` instead of `std::atomic<myObj>`.

An alternative is to implement a custom full specialization of `std::atomic<myObj>`, but that may be more work than it is worth.